# Scrape BBC Stock Market Data using rvest package in R

Tags: xml, r, pointers, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the below webpage using the rvest R package.
[BBC Stock Market Data](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business/market_data/stockmarket/default.stm)

I am looking to retrieve the Europe/Africa table in a dataframe.

My code at the moment is:

```
stockmarket <- "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business/market_data/stockmarket/default.stm"
stockmarket_html <- read_html(stockmarket)
stockmarket_perf <- html_nodes(stockmarket_html, xpath = '//*[@id="marketdata_v4"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[6]/tbody')
stockmarket_table <- html_table(stockmarket_perf)
```

but it is not working.
More specifically, when I examine the stockmarket_html document it seems that it is not an HTML but an XML pointer which I:

1. Don't know what it is
2. Don't know how to convert into an R object

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is good, your xpath is not returning any results.

Comment: Interesting, because I used the "Copy xpath" from Opera's native "Inspect Element" functionality. Can that be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you're passing to `html_nodes` isn't picking out what you want. This particular case is harder than average, as that particular table doesn't have a class or ID of its own. Nevertheless, we can grab it with

```
library(rvest)
stockmarket <- "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business/market_data/stockmarket/default.stm"
stockmarket_html <- read_html(stockmarket)
stockmarket_perf <- html_nodes(stockmarket_html, '#marketdata_v4 table')
stockmarket_table <- html_table(stockmarket_perf[9], fill = TRUE)
```

which looks for all the tables in the `marketdata_v4` `div`, and then pulls out the 9th, which is the one you want.

Note that the data is still pretty messy, and will require significant cleaning. There are alternative ways to get similar data, if you like; Yahoo Finance has a very thoroughly built API, so there are at least a couple packages that can pull from it directly if you know what you want. `quantmod` is probably worth a look, although I haven't used it for pulling indices specifically.